# Send data from js to rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a variable on controller in my project. 
I want to send variable from controller to js,
Variable is  calculate again on js and send from js to controller. but I'm failing. How can i do it? Thank you from now.

```
  %input#calculate{ type: 'text', value: "#{@cpp}", disabled: true }/
```

@cpp variable is send to js. It calculate again. Print on the screen new value. but @cpp value doen not change.

Comment: Can you provide more details? How does you controller code looks like, as well as your Rails view and JS code?

Comment: Please, add the form definition and controller method to your question.

Comment: my project details is in the comment below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**view/calculation.html.haml**

```
.container
  .calculator
    .calculator__display
      %input#calculate{ type: 'text', value: "#{@cpp}", disabled: true }/
    .calculator__keys
      %input{ onclick: 'nine()', type: 'button', value: '9' }/
      %input{ onclick: 'eight()', type: 'button', value: '8' }/
  .dropdown.position-right
    %button.btn.none-focus
      = '='
      .dropdown-content
        = link_to user_calculations_path(operation_type: "=",  calculate_piece_price: @cpp),                                                   
                method: :post,
                class: 'button btn btn-info' do
          = t('view.btn.calculation')
```

**assets/javascipts/application.js**

```
function nine(){
    var calculate =  document.getElementById("calculate");
    if (calculate.value == "0") {
        calculate.value =  "9" ;
    }
    else {
        calculate.value = calculate.value + "9";
    }
}

function eight(){
    var calculate =  document.getElementById("calculate");
    if (calculate.value == "0") {
        calculate.value =  "8" ;
    }
    else {
        calculate.value = calculate.value + "8";
    }
}
```

**controller/calculations_controller.rb**

```
  def calculation_piece_payment
    @cpp = Calculation.quantity.to_s
  end
```

Comment: You need to send/set data using AJAX (too long for an answer, sorry). Check this guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html